# How to show more columns based on window resolution?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have a row that contains two columns, I would like to show a third column only if the window is resized to a specific resolution, eg: `1920x720`. How can I do this using bootstrap?

Current HTML:

```
<div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-6">...</div>
    <div class="col-6">...</div>
</div>
```

Note that if the resolution is lower than `1920x720` then bootatrap must show only two columns, otherwise the columns in the row must be three.

Is possible achieve this only using bootstrap?

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#responsive-classes

Comment: @JeremyHarris is there a particular section which I should look?

Comment: Use `md` for large devices and `sm` form small like `.col-6 .col-md-4` for detail use the link provided by @JeremyHarris OR may be this could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39326917/how-to-set-column-classes-for-different-screen-sizes-using-bootstrap/39340914

Comment: You can do this easily if youre willing to break on the bootstrap breakpoints : 768px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built-in class to hide/show a col according to the break point :
example :

```css
.d-sm-none {background:lightgreen;}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">run me in full page to see the third column</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">2</div>
    <div class="d-sm-none d-md-block col">3</div>
</div>
```

you will find the class to use to select your breakpoints at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/display/#hiding-elements

avalaible class below, if the widest breakpoint do not match your needs, recreate a similar rule for it . Another answer gives you the clues for that.

```css
table td {
  border: solid 1px;
}
table {border-collapse:collapse;}
```

```html
>
<p>To show an element only on a given interval of screen sizes you can combine one <code class="highlighter-rouge">.d-*-none</code> class with a <code class="highlighter-rouge">.d-*-*</code> class, for example <code class="highlighter-rouge">.d-none .d-md-block .d-xl-none</code>  will hide the element for all screen sizes except on medium and large devices.</p>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Screen Size</th>
      <th>Class</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Hidden on all</td>
      <td><code class="highlighter-rouge">.d-none</code></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hidden only on xs</td>
      <td><code class="highlighter-rouge">.d-none .d-sm-block</code></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hidden only on sm</td>
      <td><code class="highlighter-rouge">.d-sm-none .d-md-block</code></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hidden only on md</td>
      <td><code class="highlighter-rouge">.d-md-none .d-lg-block</code></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hidden only on lg</td>
      <td><code class="highlighter-rouge">.d-lg-none .d-xl-block</code></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hidden only on xl</td>
      <td><code class="highlighter-rouge">.d-xl-none</code></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Visible on all</td>
      <td><code class="highlighter-rouge">.d-block</code></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Visible only on xs</td>
      <td><code class="highlighter-rouge">.d-block .d-sm-none</code></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Visible only on sm</td>
      <td><code class="highlighter-rouge">.d-none .d-sm-block .d-md-none</code></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Visible only on md</td>
      <td><code class="highlighter-rouge">.d-none .d-md-block .d-lg-none</code></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Visible only on lg</td>
      <td><code class="highlighter-rouge">.d-none .d-lg-block .d-xl-none</code></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Visible only on xl</td>
      <td><code class="highlighter-rouge">.d-none .d-xl-block</code></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


<figure class="highlight">  
  <pre><code class="language-html" data-lang="html"><span class="nt">&lt;div</span> <span class="na">class=</span><span class="s">"d-lg-none"</span><span class="nt">&gt;</span>hide on screens wider than lg<span class="nt">&lt;/div&gt;</span>
<span class="nt">&lt;div</span> <span class="na">class=</span><span class="s">"d-none d-lg-block"</span><span class="nt">&gt;</span>hide on screens smaller than lg<span class="nt">&lt;/div&gt;</span></code></pre>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 2):

### Compass approach

There are options to control the width breakpoints. This can be found in the `_variables.scss` file:

```
$grid-breakpoints: (
    xs: 0,
    sm: 576px,
    md: 768px,
    lg: 992px,
    xl: 1200px,
    xxl: 1920px // add custom breakpoint
) !default;

$container-max-widths: (
    sm: 540px,
    md: 720px,
    lg: 960px,
    xl: 1140px,
    xxl: 1880px // add custom breakpoint
) !default;
```

With this in place you can control the structure to be responsive on the xxl breakpoint.

```
<div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-6 col-xxl-4">...</div>
    <div class="col-6 col-xxl-4">...</div>
    <div class="col-4 d-none d-xxl-block">...</div>
</div>
```

### CSS Approach

Since we cannot control the device height in a media query out-of-box in Bootstrap it might be easier to override in CSS and use [auto-layout columns](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/#auto-layout-columns).

```
<div class="row"> 
    <div class="col">...</div>
    <div class="col">...</div>
    <div class="col d-none" rel="xxl">...</div>
</div>

@media (min-width: 1920px) and (min-height: 720px){
    .col[rel="xxl"] {
        display: block !important;
    }
}
```

[DEMO FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/tive/vh6fzyue/)
[DEMO RESULT](https://jsfiddle.net/tive/vh6fzyue/show/)

Comment: the attribute option seems the easiest to set in action and to maintain through time, people and updates .I would have used a custom class or a data-attribute (and eventually comments)  but it works the same and is efficient.

Comment: Ah yes, a class like `.d-xxl-block` seems more inline with the utility classes. I agree! Although the OP asked specifically to take in the height as well. These utility classes are more control for width only.

Comment: agreed, to me your answer seemed to be the one to select.

Answer (score 1):

you can't do that with bootstrap classes you need to add custom media queries for the same. in that case you dont have to use row>col-6 classes

```
<div class="wrapper"> 
<div class="first">...</div>
<div class="second">...</div>
<div class="third">...</div>
```

```
.first,.second,.third{
width:33.33%
}


@media(max-height:720px){
 .third{
 display:none
}
.first,.second{
 width:50%
}
}
```

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/display/ there is built-in classes for this already ;)  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/display/#hiding-elements

Answer (score 0):

You can use the hidden class as mention [here](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/)

For example on small device you can hide the column by adding this class: `hidden-sm-down`

Check the table there.

**Update:**

for bootstrap ver > 4 you should use like @G-Cyr said
with the class `.d-sm-none`

You can read the doc [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/display/#hiding-elements)

Comment: maybe https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/#responsive-classes & https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/display/ is a better link to propose ;)

Comment: class would be `.d-sm-none .d-md-block` now

Comment: @G-Cyr I would like to see an example provided by you, would be possible? thanks

Comment: i added an answer with an example, you had the idea first, i expected that you would update and do a snippet to demonstrate it ;)